# Minimize number of edges used when making multiple routes

Tags: graph-theory, max-flow

The title maybe isn't clear, but I'll try to explain better here:

- Suppose we have a directed weighted graph G, with N nodes and K edges.
- There is two main nodes: Node 1 and Node N. Our main goal is to go from 1 to N. And usually there is multiple possible paths from 1 to N.
- We also have M people that want to travel from 1 to N.
- Every edge has a weight w. The weight means how many people simultaneously can pass through that edge.
- Every edge can be imagined as a road, that takes 1 day to pass.

What we want to do is to make the M people go to node N, from node 1, minimizing the number of days.

For example:

[example of graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkrNF.png)

In this graph, if we have 3 people to pass, the minimum number of days is 2. We pass 2 people to the node 2 and 1 person to node 3. The 2 people will take 2 days to go to node 3, and 1 person will take 1 day to go to node 3.

My question is: How to solve this? Is it with max-flow? If yes, how to model the problem so that it can be solved with max-flow?

Answer (score 0):

- Apply max-flow algorithm in normal way
- If max-flow result is less than M

  - no solution
- If max-flow result is equal to M

  - solved
- If max-flow result is greater than M

  - remove people from max max flow result in order of longest trip until M left.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Maybe I didn't make myself clear, but in the case of max-flow less than M, it means that some people will have to "wait" until they can pass through the road. 

The solution is always the number of days that was used to transport people from node 1 to node M. So, in a graph that has only node 1 and node N and an edge with capacity 1, the number of days will always be the number of people. If the capacity is 2, than the number of days can be halved.